# Windows Store Frame Navigation: How to get the source page?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, microsoft-metro

On windows store apps we usually use something like this:

```
this.Frame.Navigate( typeof(ItemDetailPage), itemId);
```

To navigate between the app's different pages.

After the page I want to navigate to is open, how can I know it's navigation source? How can I get the previous page type?

Comment: Just to be clear - are you working with a Windows 8 (WinRT) Store app?

Comment: Yes. I have only put the windows phone tag because I think the navigation is done the same way.

Comment: They're similar, but there are differences: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.navigationeventargs - you can see what the previous page type (`SourcePageType`) was, not Uri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to create a navigated event

```
void NavigationService_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    //Your code here
}
```

(per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.navigated.aspx)

Then once you have this event you can look at the `NavigationEventArgs`

This will allow you to access the `Navigator` that called the event.

From THERE you should be able to grab the Navigator's `Uri`

Comment: But on the page I want to navigate to, I already have the method 'protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)'. Wasn't the NavigationEventArgs on there supposed do give me the URI from the previous page?

Comment: There is no Navigated event in Page type for Windows Store Apps. It's replaced with the overridable method `OnNavigatedTo`, which doesn't give any previous page information.